# Cross-correlation in matlab: symmetrical plot and sign convention

Tags: matlab, cross-correlation

I have two cosine signals in MATLAB both having a frequency of 100 Hz and the second signal has been delayed in time by 0.003 seconds. Both signals have been sampled at 1 Khz. When I use the cross correlation function and plot it to verify the delay between the signals, I expect to see a single point in time at which the signals are aligned but the plot looks symmetrical about the y axis. Why is that?

Also I am not sure about the sign convention here. Does a negative x axis value at the cross correlation peak denote time lag or does a positive x axis value denote time lag?

```
st=1/1000;
t=[0:999]*st;

s1=cos(2*pi*100*t);
t1=t-(3*st);
s2=cos(2*pi*100*t1);

[c,lags]=xcorr(s1,s2);
plot(lags,c/max(c))
```

Comment: I provided an answer below, but this question might have been more on topic on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not *exactly* symmetrical. Look where the autocorrelation has a maximal absolute value:

```
lags(abs(c)==max(abs(c)))
```

This returns `-3`, which corresponds to your delay of 0.003 s. The negative sign simply means that your second signal is delayed, not the first. If you swap them when calling `xcorr`, like that:

```
[c,lags] = xcorr(s2,s1);
lags(abs(c)==max(abs(c)))
```

then the answer will be `3`. Now it's positive.